# Decoding Bindata from MongoDB with Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, bindata

We're trying to decode BinData saved on a MongoDB database. It's a fake MAC address (11:22:33:44:55:66), saved as BinData in MongoDB (BinData(0,ESIzRFVm)) and we have no clue how to get it back. We've tried Base64 Decoding, HEX Decoding and several other ways.

This isn't so much a programming problem as it is a general decoding problem... We're just unsure how BinData is encoded and what encoding. So... How can MongoDB Bindata be decoded?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the BSON spec?  perhaps this page will help: [DataTypes](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)   It describes BinData storage